# Reexecute php function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to fetch values from MySql database every time when mouse moves. I used Javascript and Php for this.

config.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','info_schema');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Javascript (AJAX Code):

```
$(window).mousemove(function( event ) {
document.getElementById("nindicator").innerHTML="<b><?php echo dbcount();?></b>";
//alert("working");
});
```

Php function code :

```
//Database Count Function
function dbcount(){
global $conn,$temp;
$result3;
$result3=mysqli_query($conn,"Select count(*) from message_and_notifications.notifications where My_id=".$_SESSION['My_id']." and Mark_read=0");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
return $row["count(*)"];
}
```

So here dbcount() gets value and displays it for first time. After that when function is executed again it simply displays the first value without even checking the database. Hope I clarified my question. Please get back.

Comment: "I  want to fetch values from MySql database every time when mouse moves. I used Javascript and Php" - don't do it. This will take tremendous amount of resources.

Comment: You need to write an Ajax query.

Comment: You should at the very least have a delay, so you don't fire 100 requests if the user moves the cursor. I have a strong feeling this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) though. It seems you're only updating the unread notifications. Which you can do on a poll interval instead of messing with mouse move events.

Comment: Example? How to write it

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Comment: @KrishnaRajK What part of the so-called AJAX code makes it AJAX, exactly?! And you do know that `<?php echo dbcount();?>` gets executed *once*, right? Setting `innerHTML` to the same value over and over doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Yp its not ajax. Just javascript